# FB SDK crash on device iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on

I am trying toupload photo to facebook using FB SDK for iOS by going through hellofabcebook sample. I am following all the steps properly but application is getting crash on device. It wroks fine on simulator. in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
// attempt to extract a token from the url
return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
```

}

in viewcontroller viewDidLoad method

```
loginview =
[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"status_update"]];

loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
loginview.delegate = self;


[self.view addSubview:loginview];
```

when i click on loginview's login buttton ,it opens a web page asking for sign in...after sign application crashes. This behaviour is very uncertain because its working fine on simulator,iPhone4 device but not on iPhone3g. Even in iPhone4 it crashes sometimes but not always.

Comment: carsh log  NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<UIButtonContent: 0x21e500 Title = (null), Image = (null), Background = (null), TitleColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1, ShadowColor = (null)>: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: state
Observed object: <FBSession: 0x62a8b10, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 478897658797357, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x628d1d0>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate:

Comment: Just to clarify, is the HelloFacebookSample crashing or is the app you're building based on it crashing.

Comment: ny application is crashing. Its something related to FBSession. Dont know what and where I am missing

Comment: Could you perhaps show any other Facebook-related code you've added?

Comment: did you found any remedy I am having the same issue.

Comment: no man, I am using share kit now. I will try to implement using FB sdk later,if i find any solution, i will post